# How to disable show more button when all items have been displayed? Pagination API

Tags: javascript, pagination, http-get

I have a page of news , I'm showing first 6 news and then with button `ShowMore` I make additional request for news.
I have a method

```
 getLatestNews(count = 6, last = 0): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.api}/news/public/list?filter=last&limit=${count}&offset=${last}`)
  }
```

Which receives `count` as parameter of qty of news and `last` as parametr index of news array on back side.
`getLatestNews()` returns an object:

```
{
   count: 26,
   items: [....] // first 6 news
}
```

When user push the `ShowMore` button it make `showMore()` method which make additional request `getLatestNews(currentCountOfNews + 6, the latest element in array)`.
What is the best way to make my `ShowMore` button work correctly ? I need to make my button to be disabled if no result after backend request or next request would receive an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Add another value to your return such as remainingCount.

The first request response would look like.

```
{
   count: 26,
   items: [....], // first 6 news
   remaingCount: 20
}
```

Then you can use that value in the frontend in a condition and disable the button when it equals 0.

### Update:

If you can't control the backend. You need to keep track of how many items you are currently displaying and compare that to the response from the backend.

```
handleShowMore() => {
   let count = 6;
   response = getLatestNews(count, last = 0): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get(`${environment.api}/news/public/list?filter=last&limit=${count}&offset=${last}`)
   }

   if(displayedNews.length + count >= response?.count) {
      // Disable showMore button
      document.getElementById("showMore").disabled = true;
   }
   
   // Handle the rest of the response
   displayedNews.push(response.items);
}
```

Comment: good decisioun but I cant make affect to backend , so I need to find a way to check total count only or I dont know how

Answer (score 0):

To make your button to be disabled you need to get remaining data size from the API response.

```
if(remaining_data.length == 0){
    //write code to disable button
 }
```

another way : if you don't want to show ShowMore button then you can call api on page scrolling.

Comment: if I make request and it returns total qty of news is 9 and I have received 6 and I make next request which will return only 3 and it is clear that next after that request will not return any of news. So I need somehow to check also total count of received news and future ones, so user will not make useless request

Comment: Also I need to put new arguments to `getLatestNews()` and I need to know how to update this variables too